# In Kdenlive, how to change the rotate axis to a specific point?

Tags: inkscape, kdenlive, rotate

I've drawn an arm in Inkscape. I'd like to use Kdenlive to rotate the arm (from the shoulder) 90 degrees.

In Inkscape, when I want to rotate the arm, I simply change the rotation axis to the shoulder. Is it possible to do this in Kdenlive?

All I've been able to figure out so far is this:

1. Rotate from center (but the center of the arm is the elbow, not the shoulder) which doesn't work - yes, I can change the place where it ends up, but that requires middle keyframes too which is a lot of work.
2. Don't rotate from center (but I can't find a way to change the axis, so the arm flies off the body entirely) which doesn't work. (Same work-around with the end location as 1.)
3. Before importing the PNG, save as a square with the shoulder at the center of the square, then choose "rotate from center". This does work, but would require a lot of work from my end to always save in a square in Inkscape.

Thanks so much for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I asked in the Kdenlive forums, and was told that this functionality does not yet exist.